# How to return Thymeleaf page with sent Date param

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need directions how to solve issue with CRUD app. I have model  class that have Date field:

```
@Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy.")
private Date date;
```

In Thymeleaf template date field is put in textfield that using JQuery datepicker. That part working as intended.

```
<form th:action="@{/poetracker/addNew}" th:object="${item}" method="post" style="max-width:418px; margin:0 auto">
    <div class="pt-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="datepicker" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Датум:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" th:field="*{date}" readonly autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm"/>
            </div>
            //some other components rendering
        </div>
</form>
```

Now comes the part I have trouble with. When submit button is clicked, item added to database, I want form to be reloaded. But, I want date field to be remembered from last item added to database (value that was in form before Submit button clicked).

here is my Controller, what I tried:

```
@GetMapping("/addNew")
public String addNewShow(@RequestParam(name = "date", required = false) 
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) Date date, Model model) {
    Item item = new Item();
    model.addAttribute("item", item);
    item.setDate(date);
    return "/poetracker/addNew";
}
   
@PostMapping("/addNew")
public String addNew(Item item) {
    itemService.addNew(item);
    return "redirect:/poetracker/addNew";
}
```

I tested passing date through query it works, but I want to be passed just with button click. Is there recommended way to do this? Java or JQuery, doesn't matter, just curious how it is done.

UPDATE: I am looking for this kind of functionality:
In .net razor-pages I have properties

```
[BindProperty(Name = "month", SupportsGet = true)]
public int? SelectedMonth { get; set; }
[BindProperty(Name = "year", SupportsGet = true)]
public int? SelectedYear { get; set; }
[BindProperty(Name = "day", SupportsGet = true)]
public int? SelectedDay { get; set; }
```

and can redirect in Post like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await repository.CreateAsync(Item!);
        }
        return RedirectToPage("Add", new 
        {
            day = Item!.Day, month = Item!.Month, year = Item!.Year
        }); 
    }
```

Is there something like that in Java? Probably there is, I just need pointers how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve it. Not the only way and not exactly what I had in mind, but it provides desired results. Posting it, just in case someone need solution to similar problem:

```
@PostMapping("/addNew")
public String addNew(Item item) {
    itemService.addNew(item);
    LocalDate date = item.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    String selectedDate = String.format("%d-%d-%d", date.getYear(), date.getMonthValue(), date.getDayOfMonth());
    String route = "redirect:/poetracker/addNew?date=" + selectedDate;
    return route;
}
```